# Cohomology ring of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ be the Hopf bundle over $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^\infty$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the trivial rank one bundle. Consider the projectivization of the rank two bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \mathcal{O}$. This is a bundle over $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^\infty$ with fiber $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$.

**How to describe explicitly the cohomology ring of this space?**

Sorry if this question is more appropriate for Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Here $\mathcal O$ is the trivial rank 1 bundle? So your sum has Chern class 1-x. The projective bundle formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_bundle#Cohomology_ring_and_Chow_group) gives you that your total space has cohomology ring $\Bbb Z[x, \zeta]/(\zeta^2-x\zeta)$. If you instead meant the projectivization of $\mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(1)$, the formula instead gives $\Bbb Z[x, \zeta]/(\zeta^2-x^2)$. In any case, the Gysin sequence implies that $H^*(E)$ is a free module of rank 2 over $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: Yes, this is the trivial rank one bundle. Thank you.